# How can I bind a component method to a ViewModel in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, methods, extjs, controller

In ExtJS 6.02, if I have this:

```js
Ext.define('MyController', {
     extend : 'Ext.app.ViewController'
   , alias  : 'controller.myWindowController'
   , onShow: function() {
       console.log('IT SHOWS!');
   }
});

Ext.define('MyWindow', {
     extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
     controller: 'myWindowController',
     show: 'onShow'
});

ExtCreate('MyWindow', {}).show();  // Gives error here, `show` is a string now!
```

How can I bind component methods to the controller?
Or is it only possible to bind events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is overriding the [show method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-show).  Instead, it seems like you want to listen for when show is fired... to do that, you'd tap into the [listeners](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-listeners) config, and listen for the [show](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#event-show) event, like this:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    controller: 'myWindowController',
    listeners: {
        show: 'onShow'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I can do it on this case. But how about if there's something that I really need to override? In this case would it still be possible to do it on the viewController?

Comment: Directly on the `ViewController`, no, as `show` is a method on your View.  You could potentially override the show method in your View to call a method in the ViewController, but I would question why you have to do this in the first place.

Comment: I have a case here where I have some radiogroups and I want to create a `refresh` method on them, and call it when my window is shown. Another option would be to change the radio groups from the shown method, but I think it would be nicer if I just call the `refresh` and the radiogroup changes itself.

Comment: That would not warrant overriding the `show` method.  Honestly, you should only override the framework methods if there's a bug, or you need to enhance it in some fashion.  In this scenario, you're better off using events/listeners.

Comment: The `refresh` method would not override anything, it would be a new method.

Comment: Correct, you said you wanted to override `show` to add the `refresh` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232250/discussion-between-user5507535-and-incutonez).